# Dismiss UIPopoverController on didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, ios5

I have implemented `UIPopoverController` with storyboard but i am not able to make it dismiss when I select particular row in `UITableView`.[image]

When select particular row so that time I want to dismiss the popover but I am not able dismiss it.

I write below code for this:

//Show the popover in Main UIViewController

```
-(IBAction)clickNotes:(id)sender {
     NSLog(@"notes:");   
    NoteList *objNoteList = [[NoteList alloc] initWithNibName:@"NoteList" bundle:nil];
    popover.delegate = self;
    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:objNoteList];
    popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(250, 450);
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(730, 0, 1,1) inView:self.view     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES]; 
    }
```

//Hide the popover in another UIViewController on didSelecteRowAtIndexPath

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
   {    
   Notepad_ipad *objNote = [[Notepad_ipad alloc] init];      
   NSString *mSelectedNoteText = @"Selected text"; 
   [objNote SelectedNote:mSelectedNoteText];
   [objNote.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code instantiates a NEW Instance. So it has nothing to do with the already existing popover :`Notepad_ipad *objNote = [[Notepad_ipad alloc] init];`

Also Instead Of :

```
popover.delegate = self;
popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:objNoteList];
```

USE:

```
popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:objNoteList];
popover.delegate = self;
```

I.e.: Allocate the instance first and then set its `delegate`.

Finally replace your method
 `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath`

with this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)    indexPath   {    
[popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// Create protocol in .h file of controller which contains `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method as follows:

```
@protocol Popoverdelegate <NSObject>
{

  -(void)didRowAtIndexPathIsSelected;

}


// Add this property in .h file of the same controller

@property (strong, nonatomic) id<Popoverdelegate> delegate;


//  Now implement this protocol in interface which calls popovercontroller 

// for ex:   @interface ViewController <Popovercontroller>

// then add following properties to viewController .h file

@protocol (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *popoverController; 


// Implement popoverdelegate protocol in .m file as

- (void) didRowAtIndexPathIsSelected
{

  [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

}


// Replace your code as follows


-(IBAction)clickNotes:(id)sender 
{

    NoteList *objNoteList = [[NoteList alloc] initWithNibName:@"NoteList" bundle:nil];
    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:objNoteList];   
    popover.delegate = self;
    self.popoverController = popover;

    self.popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(250, 450);
    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(730, 0, 1,1) inView:self.view     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES]; 
    }

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{    
     Notepad_ipad *objNote = [[Notepad_ipad alloc] init];      
     NSString *mSelectedNoteText = @"Selected text"; 
     [objNote SelectedNote:mSelectedNoteText];
    [self.delegate dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The smartest thing to do here (imho) is to follow this example code, I do it every time:

```
// firstViewController.h
@interface firstViewController : UIViewController <SecondDelegate>
{
   SecondViewController *choice;
}

// firstViewController.m
- (void)choicePicked(NSString *)choice
{
   NSLog(choice);
   [_popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; //(put it here)
   _popover = nil; (deallocate the popover)
   _choicePicker = nil; (deallocate the SecondViewController instance)
}

// secondViewController.h (the one that will give back the data)
@protocol SecondDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)choicePicked:(NSString *)choice;
@end
@interface secondViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <SecondDelegate> delegate;
@end

// secondViewController.m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *selection = [_yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[self delegate] choicePicked:selection];
}
```